# Error when creating new RDOSession using RedemptionLoader

Tags: outlook, outlook-redemption

Below is my code:

```
RDOSession pstSession = null;
string binPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
RedemptionLoader.DllLocation64Bit = Path.Combine(binPath, "Redemption64.dll");
RedemptionLoader.DllLocation32Bit = Path.Combine(binPath, "Redemption.dll");
pstSession = RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();
```

> Error logged is:
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8004010F): Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {29AB7A12-B531-450E-8F7A-EA94C2F3C05F} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 8004010f Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004010F.

Searched the error code but could not get much information. What might be the problem? The issue is not replicated in every machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x8004010F` is `MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND`, which most likely means Redemption cannot find the MAPI system, either because it is not present (Outlook must be installed) or it has a wrong bitness. See http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#ErrorCreatingRedemptionObject for more details.